# How I can change display from 12:00 to 00:00

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 with razor engine view.
the code to appear a datetime value is:

Server: obj.Inicio = DateTime.Now.Date
Client: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Inicio, "{0:hh:mm:ss}")

I want display it in pt-BR format, but it always show 12:00:00, and the correct form be 00:00:00.

anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at format strings [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

But to answer your question, hh is 12 hour and HH is 24 hour

```
{0:hh:mm:ss} ------> {0:HH:mm:ss}
```